# Error when trying to install Flask extensions

Tags: python, flask

I'm working through the following tutorial:

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

I have created a virtual environment and have been trying to install the following extensions:

```
flask/bin/pip install flask==0.9
flask/bin/pip install flask-login
flask/bin/pip install flask-openid
flask/bin/pip install flask-mail==0.7.6
flask/bin/pip install sqlalchemy==0.7.9
flask/bin/pip install flask-sqlalchemy==0.16
flask/bin/pip install sqlalchemy-migrate==0.7.2
flask/bin/pip install flask-whooshalchemy==0.54a
flask/bin/pip install flask-wtf==0.8.4
flask/bin/pip install pytz==2013b
flask/bin/pip install flask-babel==0.8
flask/bin/pip install flup
```

When I run them I get the following error message for each one:

```
Wheel installs require setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info support.
pip's wheel support requires setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info support.
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/seanpatterson/.pip/pip.log
```

From reading my thoughts are I'm running an old version of setup tools, but I'm not sure how to upgrade this, or what setup file it would be. Any thoughts?

Comment: You should install setuptools first :) use this command: `pip install setuptools`

Answer (score 1):

`pip install -U setuptools` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but Ive just tried but it says '-bash: pip: command not found' ?!?!

Comment: Ah yes, you will have to use the absolute path if you don't use `virtualenv`'s `activate` script:
`flask/bin/pip install -U setuptools`
[e]: Sorry, didn't see the answer below. Disregard this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
flask/bin/pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

If you don't specify the pip in your virtual environment your system will look through its `$PATH` for `pip`. Your virtual environment probably isn't in one of the directories in the system path and as a result won't be found.

Comment: Thanks for the help but still getting this message, when I try and do that.  `sim1-3010:microblog seanpatterson$ flask/bin/pip install --upgrade setuptools
Wheel installs require setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info support.
pip's wheel support requires setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info support.
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/seanpatterson/.pip/pip.log`.  Does it matter where I run this command from? At the moment I'm running from the folder where my flask application sits - presumably where my virtual env is located.